# frame problem with pre-defined environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to adapt existing files into a beamer presentation. All of them have a pre-defined `question` environment, which I need to change.

In `testcontent.tex`, I have

```
\section*{first section}

%%Q1
\begin{question}
The line $y=a^2 x$ and  the curve  $y=x(b-x)^2$, where $0<a<b\,$, intersect at the origin $O$ and at points $P$ and $Q $. The $x$-coordinate of $P$ is less than the $x$-coordinate  of $Q$. Find the coordinates of $P$  and $Q$, and sketch the line and the curve   on the same axes. 
\end{question}

%%Q2
\begin{question}
If $x=\log_b(c)\,$, express $c$ in terms of $b$ and $x$ and prove that $ \dfrac{\log_a (c)}{\log_a (b)} = \ds \log_b (c) \,$.
\end{question}


\section*{last section}
%%Q3
\begin{question}
The line $y=a^2 x$ and  the curve  $y=x(b-x)^2$, where $0<a<b\,$, intersect at the origin $O$ and at points $P$ and $Q $. The $x$-coordinate of $P$ is less than the $x$-coordinate  of $Q$. Find the coordinates of $P$  and $Q$, and sketch the line and the curve   on the same axes. 
\end{question}

%%Q4
\begin{question}
If $x=\log_b(c)\,$, express $c$ in terms of $b$ and $x$ and prove that $ \dfrac{\log_a (c)}{\log_a (b)} = \ds \log_b (c) \,$.
\end{question}
```

What I want to do is to put questions on **each frame** (allow breaks for long questions), so I did

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}

\newenvironment{question}%
{
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]%
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries Q1\quad][10]%
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
        \item%
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\input{testcontent}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adaptations:**

- added options `fragile, environment=question` to `frame` environment
- removed `[\bfseries Q1\quad][10]`, as default enumerate has no options

  - use `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{Q\arabic{enumi}}` instead
- removed undefined command `\ds`

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}


\newenvironment{question}%
{
\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=question,allowframebreaks]
    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{Q\arabic{enumi}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
        \item%
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{first section}

%%Q1
\begin{question}
    The line $y=a^2 x$ and  the curve  $y=x(b-x)^2$, where $0<a<b\,$, intersect at the origin $O$ and at points $P$ and $Q $. The $x$-coordinate of $P$ is less than the $x$-coordinate  of $Q$. Find the coordinates of $P$  and $Q$, and sketch the line and the curve   on the same axes.
\end{question}

%%Q2
\begin{question}
If $x=\log_b(c)\,$, express $c$ in terms of $b$ and $x$ and prove that $ \dfrac{\log_a (c)}{\log_a (b)} = \log_b (c) \,$.
\end{question}


\section*{last section}
%%Q3
\begin{question}
The line $y=a^2 x$ and  the curve  $y=x(b-x)^2$, where $0<a<b\,$, intersect at the origin $O$ and at points $P$ and $Q $. The $x$-coordinate of $P$ is less than the $x$-coordinate  of $Q$. Find the coordinates of $P$  and $Q$, and sketch the line and the curve   on the same axes. 
\end{question}

%%Q4
\begin{question}
If $x=\log_b(c)\,$, express $c$ in terms of $b$ and $x$ and prove that $ \dfrac{\log_a (c)}{\log_a (b)} = \log_b (c) \,$.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really notice the `\ds`, but that's not a problem at all. Is there a way to make it workable for `input` where the file also has a preamble? I mean the `testcontent.tex` works fine if it does not have preamble. But when it does, Beamer couldn't compile again...I have also tried `include`...

Comment: `\usepackage{standalone}` did the trick! Thanks.